# Email validation not stopping the web page from submitting the form php

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    if(isset($_POST['email'])
        && isset($_POST['name'])) {

            if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                    $nameErr = "Name is required";
            }
            else {
                    $name = $_POST["name"];
                    var_dump($name);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace  for first name
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space 
                                         allowed";
                    }
            }



            if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                    $emailErr = "Email is required";
            }
            else {
                    $email = $_POST["email"];
                    var_dump($email);
                    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
                    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
                    }
            }


            if($data = $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
                   $_POST['email'] . "\n" . 
                   $_POST['phone'] . "\n" .
                   $_POST['county'] . "\n" . 
                   $_POST['floor'] . "\n" . 
                   $_POST['descr'] . "\n"){



                    echo "Thank you for your inquery!" . "<br/>" .
                            "an estimator will be with you shortly.";

                    mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Estimation Request', 
                         $data);
            }
    }

    else {
            die('no post data to process');
    }

?>
```

The output:

> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "Nicholas Cox" ["email"]=> string(6)
>   "######" ["phone"]=> string(10) "0000000000" ["county"]=> string(8)
>   "Pinellas" ["descr"]=> string(15) "Thesh " }
>
> string(12) "Nicholas Cox" string(6) "######"

Thank you for your inquery!
an estimator will be with you shortly.\n\nInvalid email format\n

> **Note:** if i missed taking out some of my troubleshooting steps like the random echos or die functions please let me know so i can edit to
>   help you be able to read it easier

I have not added validation on the other fields. I'm just trying to get the email and name to work before i add to the others.

Right now, when i add random stuff it will still prompt me with my error message but it still allows anything to be put in the text field AND sends the email. I've watched a few tutorials on youtube and i still can't get it right.

Comment: Well, there isn't much to say. You check for errors and remember them by means of `$nameErr` and `$emailErr`; however, you are then proceeding to process the form and send the email regardless of these. So yeah. Revise your logic. ;)

Comment: The only thing you check to send the mail or not is if the mail is "set", meaning that the `$_POST['email']` exists with any value possible. And then send the mail to this value.

Comment: What is your intention behind this condition anyway? `if($data = $_POST['name']."\n".$_POST['email']."\n".$_POST['phone']."\n".$_POST['county']."\n".$_POST['floor']."\n".$_POST['descr'] . "\n")` - it will most likely be always `true`.

Comment: Just add a line after the validation logic (before `if($data = $_POST['name'] . "\n" .`)to check if `$emailErr` is set, if so die with an error message. Example: `if($emailErr){ die($emailErr);}`

Comment: domdom: Please elaborate on me reversing it. Because i was thinking that i had to validate it first before sending the mail. Since the code reads from top to bottom.

Comment: domdom: I'm still very new to code and that sets the variable and stores it. It was just easier for me to read. i figured it would work better than to manually create the variables then store them.

Comment: Japeth Ongeri: Would this work? https://bpaste.net/show/714b2acc2312

Comment: in your link, there is a condition in `else`, which should not be.

Comment: Oh that last else. I really need to learn to clean up when i change stuff.

Comment: Done. btw this is what i'm working with now https://bpaste.net/show/942c19dddd55 your advice actually worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example what you can do with validation with your code.

```
<?php
            var_dump($_POST);
        $errorArr = array(); //Error Messages in array
            if(isset($_POST['email'])
                && isset($_POST['name'])) {

                    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                            $errorArr['nameErr'] = "Name is required"; //Error Messages in array
                    }
                    else {
                            $name = $_POST["name"];
                            var_dump($name); // This should be commented
             // check if name only contains letters and whitespace  for first name
                            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                                    $errorArr['nameErr'] = "Only letters and white space 
                                                 allowed";//Error Messages in array
                            }
                    }



                    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                            $errorArr['emailErr'] = "Email is required";
                    }
                    else {
                            $email = $_POST["email"];
                            var_dump($email); // This should be commented
                            // check if e-mail address is well-formed
                            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                                    $errorArr['emailErr'] = "Invalid email format";
                            }
                    }

        //Check Condition for any error
                    if(empty($errorArr)){

                           $data = $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
                           $_POST['email'] . "\n" . 
                           $_POST['phone'] . "\n" .
                           $_POST['county'] . "\n" . 
                           $_POST['floor'] . "\n" . 
                           $_POST['descr'] . "\n"

                            echo "Thank you for your inquery!" . "<br/>" .
                                    "an estimator will be with you shortly.";

                            mail('theshadowcallsu@gmail.com', 'Estimation Request', 
                                 $data);
                    } else {
    var_dump($errorArr); //Show Error Message
                    }
            }

            else {
                    die('no post data to process');
            }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are other issues, the problem that made you ask here lies within this condition:

```
if ($data = $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
           $_POST['email'] . "\n" . 
           $_POST['phone'] . "\n" .
           $_POST['county'] . "\n" . 
           $_POST['floor'] . "\n" . 
           $_POST['descr'] . "\n")
```

I really don't know what your intention behind it is, but let's take it apart:

- `$_POST` contains strings
- `.` concatenates strings
- `\n` is a line break

Hence, the whole thing, simplified, boils down to:

```
if ($data = $someLongStringFromMyPostValues)
```

Now, `$data = $something` is an [assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) and an [expression](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php). In PHP (and many other languages), such an assignment evaluates (returns) the value that was assigned. In other words, this sets your `$data` variable to the long string, but *regarding the condition*, this is pretty much equivalent to:

```
if ($someLongStringFromMyPostValues)
```

Due to [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in PHP, [a string with something (other than `0`) in it will be `true`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). Seeing how you add line breaks to the string, this means that, no matter what is in your `$_POST` values, this will always evaluate to (again, ignoring `$data` for now):

```
if (true)
```

You are, in no way, regarding the `$nameErr` or `$emailErr` variables that you set before that. So, whatever your intention, you need to fix this condition and incorporate your error variables into it.

Comment: I see what you mean. I had that there because i originally had it writing to a file and then i realized that was an extra step so i took it out but never fixed that part

Comment: To add on i have those string concatenated so that it formats correctly when its sent in the email.

Comment: That might make sense, just not in the `if` condition. ;)